# Play sound when press back button (No Animation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a code that play sounds when the user tap the back bar button in navigation bar, here is the code:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) SoundPlayer *soundPlayer;

- (IBAction)voltar:(id)sender{
    [self.soundPlayer PlaySound:@"back" extension:@"mp3" loops:0];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My code works very well, but I have a problem! I want to make a different type of animation when my view disappear, and for this I need to set the **popViewControllerAnimated** to **NO**.

When I do this kind of thing my player don't play sound! But why? I think because with **NO** animations the view will dealloc and the sound not will play, when animation is **YES** the sound play very well, because there must be a short delay until the view out of the scene.

My last try is with **ViewWillDisappear**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.soundPlayer PlaySound:@"back" extension:@"mp3" loops:0];
}
```

Here is the animation that I use to dismiss my view:

```
-(void)setAnimation{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
}
```

How I can solve this problem?

> Solution

I can solve this problem creating a code that will sleep my code before view goes out:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1f];
```

I believe it is not the most professional way to solve this kind of thing, but ...

> Solution 2

Hey we can use a callback when the transition finish :D

```
-(void)setAnimation{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self.soundPlayer PlaySound:@"back" extension:@"mp3" loops:0];
}
```

Well I think thats the best way and professional way to solve this problem (Better than Sleep that jerry-rig)

> Correction

Well I realized some test on this code and see that the **animationDidStop** don't play a sound, the code that play sound is **viewDidDisappear**, but why?

Lets think... When I give delegate to self in my animation, my code owes the execution of a code when the animation stop, even when everything is taken from the scene (I think).

But in this time the **viewDidDisappear** is called... and execute the song. So... All I needed to do is giving the delegate to my animation and put the sound inside **viewDidDisappear** and delete the method **animationDidStop** *(Like a bug, strange...)*

Comment: Have you tried to play sound in a different thread?

Comment: @zcui93 With GDC? Yes I try but not work...

Comment: Just create a singleton to play sounds. A manager that will handle it all. Some enumerations may be nice to indicate what sound to play. Next to that you may then control on what to do if for instance another sound should play while you are still playing a certain sound... A general way of doing such things.

Answer (score 1):

Your current view controller is likely going out of memory and losing reference to soundPlayer.

While you could totally use a singleton to manager sound playback you might be better off using a delegation/block pattern here:

In your current view controllers header you could:

```
@protocol ViewControllerBLifeCycleDelegate : NSObject
- (void)vcWillDisappear:(UIViewController *)vc;
@end

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewControllerBLifeCycleDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In the implementation of the current vc:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.delegate vcWillDisappear:self];
}
```

And finally you can make the presenting view controller the delegate of this view controller and fire your sound in that controller

```
@interface ViewControllerA () <ViewControllerBLifeCycleDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) SoundPlayer *soundPlayer;
@end
@implementation ViewControllerA
- (void)presentNextViewController {
    ViewControllerB *vc = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

- (void)vcWillDisappear:(UIViewController *)vc {
    [self.soundPlayer PlaySound:@"back" extension:@"mp3" loops:0];
}
@end
```

Comment: You can also totally do this with blocks